# Netbeans - storing GUI components made with GUI Builder in an array

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Say I have n numbered components, e.g. n jPanels called panel1, panel2, ..., paneln, that were created using Netbeans' GUI Builder. As far as I'm aware the GUI Builder doesn't allow me to store components in an array when creating them, which means if I wanted to modify them during execution I'd have to do something like

```
jPanel[] panels = new jPanel[n];
panels[1] = panel1;
panels[2] = panel2;
.
.
.
panels[n] = paneln;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //Do stuff with panels[i]
}
```

Is there some other way to do this without having to drop the Builder and create the interface from scratch?

Comment: *Is there some other way to do this without having to drop the Builder and create the interface from scratch?* - that is the better approach. That way you spend the time learning Java/Swing, instead of the IDE. Interfaces created manually are easier to maintain and the code is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code:

```
List<JPanel> myPanels = new ArrayList<>(); 
private JPanel getNewPanel()
{
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    myPanels.add(panel);
    return panel;
}
```

Then in the Netbeans GUI builder:

1. Using ctrl-click select all the panels you want to access via
   myPanels
2. In the Code tab of the Properties window, set the Custom Creation Code to: `getNewPanel();`

Answer (score 0):

Large picture: create a class that extends the component you wish to use then use that class in the IDE.

Details:

1. Open a blank java file and paste the following code:

   ```
    public class CheckBoxArray()
    {
        ndx = nextNdx++;
        jcbList.add(  this );

        addItemListener(
                new ItemListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent evt )
                    {
                        d();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------ end of class constructor -------------------------------------------------------------

    public void d()
    {
        System.out.println( "This is component " + ndx + " in array." );
    }

    public CheckBoxArray get( byte nth )
    {
        return jcbList.get( nth );
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------- end of method get ----------------------------------------------------------

    public byte length()
    {
        return nextNdx;
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------- end of method length ----------------------------------------------------------
   }
   // </editor-fold>
   // ------------------------------------------------------------ end of class CheckBoxArray------------------------------------------------------------
   ```
2. Compile the above
3. Drag from Files CheckBoxArray into whatever panel you want the component to appear.
4. Rename the component to be your base name.  So if you want array named blocks name 1st "blocks".
5. Use copy/paste to replicate component # of times you need.  Each will be automatically named +1 from the base name (blocks, blocks1, blocks2, etc.)
6. From there on use just blocks to access the array of components as follows:
   CheckBoxArray myblock4 = blocks.get( 4 );
7. Uses Properties as normal to set whatever you need.  BTW, remove the event handler if you want each component to respond uniquely to user's selection/deselection or leave as is to have every component feed into same handler (using ndx to figure out which component event came from!).